# Traeffik does not map incoming 443 to port 80 internally

Tags: traefik

Our problem is that traffic from the https entrypoint is (probably) forwarded to the backend with the wrong port. Accessing the http entrypoint works as expected: the traffic is loadbalanced between server 1 2 3. when using the https entrypoint, we get a 404 page not found. The TLS is all good, the connection is secure, but it looks like traefik does not change the port for the backend server to :80.

We do let's encrypt via traefik and this looks good.

Here's how we start traffic:

```
docker run -d -p 443:443 -p 80:80 -v /home/pi/lbtest/traefik/traefik.toml:/traefik.toml -v /home/pi/lbtest/traefik/acme.json:/acme.json traefik
```

And this is our traefik.toml

```
debug = true

[file]

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[frontends]
  [frontends.lbtest]
  backend = "lbtest"
    [frontends.lbtest.routes.route0]
    rule = "Host:xxx.gotdns.ch"

[backends]
  [backends.lbtest]
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server1]
    url = "http://192.168.178.81:80"
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server2]
    url = "http://192.168.178.49:80"
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server3]
    url= "http://192.168.178.64:80"


[acme]
email = "xxx@xxx.eu.com"
storageFile = "acme.json"
acmeLogging = true
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
main = "xxx.gotdns.ch"
```

Why does http://xxx.gotdns.ch work - it loadbalances between server 1 2 3 - but not for https://xxx.gotdns.ch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's problem with the field `defaultEntryPoints` in your configuration:

```
debug = true

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"] # <-- move the field here

[file]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[frontends]
  [frontends.lbtest]
  backend = "lbtest"
    [frontends.lbtest.routes.route0]
    rule = "Host:xxx.gotdns.ch"

[backends]
  [backends.lbtest]
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server1]
    url = "http://192.168.178.81:80"
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server2]
    url = "http://192.168.178.49:80"
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server3]
    url= "http://192.168.178.64:80"


[acme]
email = "xxx@xxx.eu.com"
storageFile = "acme.json"
acmeLogging = true
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
main = "xxx.gotdns.ch"
```

I recommend to write your configuration like that:

```
debug = true

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "xxx@xxx.eu.com"
storageFile = "acme.json"
acmeLogging = true
entryPoint = "https"
onHostRule = true

[acme.httpChallenge]
entryPoint = "http"

[[acme.domains]]
main = "xxx.gotdns.ch"

[file]
[frontends]
  [frontends.lbtest]
  backend = "lbtest"
    [frontends.lbtest.routes.route0]
    rule = "Host:xxx.gotdns.ch"

[backends]
  [backends.lbtest]
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server1]
    url = "http://192.168.178.81:80"
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server2]
    url = "http://192.168.178.49:80"
    [backends.lbtest.servers.server3]
    url= "http://192.168.178.64:80"
```

Comment: I have the same situation. How can I set the same config using container label?
I use docker-compose to handle all my service.
One of our container have to link another container using url: https://www.example.com which is another container.
But I will get the wrong port because of link was changed to 172.17.0.x:443 port that I cant use.
It should be 172.17.0.x:80.
Any idea ?